# How to close a tab with a keyboard shortcut in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, shortcut, key-bindings

[image]

I want to close the currently foreground file (tab) without closing the other items in this pane (the settings window, other open file)

`ctrl-w` is bound to pane:close this does not do what i want.

`ctrl-shift-t` is bound to pane:reopen-closed-item this does the opposite of what I want, but I cannot find the inverse of this

I want a keyboard shortcut equivalent to clicking the small x on the tab.

I have searched quite a bit, and cannot find a package or keybinding that provides this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by a little search I found this discussion inside of atom forum which says:

> If you search in Settings > Keybindings for “pane” you’ll find that `⌘K⌘W` is mapped to pane:close. You can either use that mapping or a new one of your own devising to map to pane:close.

this is the link https://discuss.atom.io/t/close-pane-keyboard-shortcut/5701

** ---- update ---- **

I downloaded and installed the atom on my windows and saw the `ctrl-w` works pretty ok so I looked at the settings and saw it set to `core:close` command

Comment: Thanks for the response. pane:close will close all items contained in the pane, not just the active tab. as I said in my post, pane:close does not do what I am looking for.

Comment: THANK YOU -- somewhere i must have remapped that. core:close is what i was looking for.

Comment: happy to help :)